# Create app with PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm trying to build an app using PhoneGap but I'm having some hard times since I'm fairly new to this "IDE". 
What I want to do is incredibly simple: open address book, select a contact and when I do so the app automatically adds a prefix to the contact's number and then start a phonecall... 
I've already done this for Android but I decided to switch to PhoneGap cause I need a lightweight app that's also universal... 
Any help?
I've read the config.xml and seen that there is a core plugin that manages contacts but I'm not getting how to use it. 
For example: when the app is started I want it to load automatically the address book (so I believe there should be a sort of eventlistener maybe?!)...

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is based on html, css and js as you know.
If you are looking for eventlistener, of course you could use something like,

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onPause, false);

For more event, please refer

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html

About contacts plugin, please refer

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts

It'll give you ideas of how to install and use the plugin.